# How can I see drop of performance in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hi i have an app where I have two components : `Home` and `UserProfil`. On `Home` component, I have a flatlist and on `UserProfil` I'm giving some more informations about the user. The thing is that when I click on a user in my flatlist, it take 2sec to redirect me to `UserProfil`. And when I activate `Show Perf Monitor` I saw that the JS drops ? Is there a way to see which is making this drop ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView, AppState, Dimensions, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import UserItem from './UserItem';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';


const numColumns = 2;

class Accueil extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
      latitude:null,
      longitude:null,
      dataSource:[],
      error:null,
      appState: AppState.currentState,
      currentIndex: 0,
    }
    this.displayPosition = this.displayPosition.bind(this);
  }

  displayPosition = () => {
      this.watchId = Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          let obj = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null
          }
          this.setState(obj);
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000},
      );
      if(this.state.latitude!=null){
        this.getData();
      } else {
        setTimeout(this.displayPosition.bind(this),200)
      }
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState (
      {
        refreshing: true,
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({refreshing: false});
        this.displayPosition();
      }
    );
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.displayPosition();
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ refresh: this._handleRefresh });
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  getData(){
    fetch("someURL")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        return(
        this.setState({
          dataSource: result
        }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        //console.error(error)
      })
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
      {this.handleRefresh()};
    }
  };


  /*
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    return {
      headerRight: () => (
        <View style={{marginLeft: 8, marginRight: 8, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginRight: 10 }} onPress={ () =>{ }}>
              {/*<Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/search.png")} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }} onPress={ () =>{{this.displayPosition()}}}>
              {/*<Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/localisation.png")} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 10 }} onPress={ () => {this.handleRefresh()}}>
              {/*<Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/refresh.png")} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ),
    };
  };
*/

  _displayDetailForUser = (idUser, name, photo, age, pratique, description, distance, Statut, localisation, principale, certifie, nb_photos, bloque, date_last_conn, link, Ville_sec, index) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("UserProfil", { MembreId: idUser, Pseudo:name, Photo: photo, Age:age, Genre:pratique, 
      Description:description,  delta:distance, Statut:Statut, CP:localisation, Ville:principale, p_certifie:certifie, nb_photos: nb_photos, 
      bloque:bloque, date_last_conn:date_last_conn, link:link, Ville_sec:Ville_sec, index:index});
  }

  _displaySwipe = (idUser, index) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('UserProfil', {
      data: this.state.dataSource, MembreId:idUser, index:index});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
          <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          extraData = {this.state}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.MembreId}
          renderItem={(item) => <UserItem user={item} displayDetailForUser={this._displayDetailForUser} displaySwipe = {this._displaySwipe}/>}
          numColumns={numColumns}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

export default Accueil
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: I've edited the post with the code